# Difference between renraku-waza and renzoku-waza

Tags: judo, terminology, japanese

Judo has a lot of terms inherited from Japanese. Two such are *[renraku](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%A1#Japanese)-* and *[renzoku](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E7%B6%9A#Japanese)-waza*. In the [BJA syllabus](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/53/) these are translated as:

> Renzoku-waza is the Japanese terminology for combinations of attacks that continue in the same direction. Renraku-waza are combinations of attacks where you CHANGE direction.

But this doesn't seem obvious from the usual meanings of the words in Japanese ("sequence [of techniques]", and "connected [techniques]" respectively). Is this an accurate description of how these judo terms are used in Japan? If not, how are they used?

Answer (score 5):

The Kodokan has expressed [similar thoughts](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/2015/):

> In parallel, there were request and discussions for the unification and explanation of Judo terms. Terms casually used such as Uchi-komi, Kakari-renshu, Yakusoku-renshu, Nage-komi, Sute-geiko, **Renraku-waza**, Henka-waza, Tachi-waza, Ne-waza, Suri-ashi, Ayumi-ashi, and Tsugi-ashi can be more or less understood by the kanji meanings but foreigners must understand these terms when these names are written in alphabets. Therefore, **it is necessary to explain the meanings of these Judo terms in accurate English.**
>
> For the requests up until now, the Waza Research Committee classified them after repeated discussions and responded after translating into English. After this, production of a "Judo Glossary", that is an enhanced version of the "Kodokan New Japanese-English Dictionary of Judo" that was published in 2000, will be undertaken immediately.

While the aforementioned [judo glossary](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/waza/dictionary/) is still unpublished, the original dictionary says this:

| 連絡 (renraku) | 連続 (renzoku) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |